# How I can sort this data out in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is similar to these data. However, I have more than these columns

```
n1<-10
n2<-11
n3<-12
n4<-13
n5<-14

df<-read.table (text=" A1   A2  A3  A4  A5
        12  11  11  12  14
        13  10  13  14  12
        8   12  14  14  16
        16  14  16  12  13
        13  19  14  11  11
        ", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table:

```
O1  O2  O3  O4  O5
Y   Y   N   N   Y
Y   N   Y   Y   N
N   Y   Y   Y   Y
Y   Y   Y   N   N
Y   Y   Y   N   N
1   1   1   3   3
```

The logic is that, for example, in the O1 column, if the values are >= n1, it gets Y, else N. For the O2 column, n2 is considered and n3 for O3 and n4 for O4 and n5 goes to O5. Finally, I want to get the count Ns for each column.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use a `list`

```
df[] <- c("N", "Y")[1+(df >= mget(ls(pattern = "^n\\d+$")))]
```

Or it can be also done by `paste` and `mget`

```
df[] <- c("N", "Y")[1+(df >= mget(paste0("n", 1:5)))]
```

Comment: Is it possible to not mention  n1, n2... in case we have a lot of ns? Otherwise, we have to address  all possible ns, which is tedious.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the desired table: No Eror

Comment: @user330 sorry, there was a mistake.  I should have added 1

Comment: I see these codes do not work for decimal numbers. the issue is >= I think. It does not recognise the sign of the equal?

Comment: @user330 Do you need `>` instead of `>=` because equality with floating numbers depend on precision and it may be the issue

Answer (score 2):

A simple base R option using `t`

```
df[] <- c("N", "Y")[t(t(df) >= c(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)) + 1]
```

gives

```
> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  Y  Y  N  N  Y
2  Y  N  Y  Y  N
3  N  Y  Y  Y  Y
4  Y  Y  Y  N  N
5  Y  Y  Y  N  N
```

and then you use `rbind` to get

```
> rbind(df, colSums(df == "N"))
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  Y  Y  N  N  Y
2  Y  N  Y  Y  N
3  N  Y  Y  Y  Y
4  Y  Y  Y  N  N
5  Y  Y  Y  N  N
6  1  1  1  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more concise way to do this, but here's how I would think about it:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First, convert your n's to a lookup table. I'd rather keep them all in one place rather than as separate variables. This also would make it more convenient if the column names are programmatically determined, e.g. we could use `col = paste0("A", 1:5)` here instead.

```
n <- tibble(col = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"),
            n = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
```

Then convert `df` to long format, join to `n`, do the comparison, and then pivot wide again:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = "col", values_to = "val") %>%
  left_join(n) %>%
  mutate(greater = if_else(val >= n, "Y", "N")) %>%
  select(row, col, greater) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = greater) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  A1    A2    A3    A4    A5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Y     Y     N     N     Y    
2 Y     N     Y     Y     N    
3 N     Y     Y     Y     Y    
4 Y     Y     Y     N     N    
5 Y     Y     Y     N     N
```

To add the totals in the last row, here's a way. Let's say the output above was saved to `temp`. Then:

```
bind_rows(
  temp, 
  temp %>% 
    summarize(
      across(
        everything(),
        ~sum(.x == "Y") %>%
          as.character())))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  A1    A2    A3    A4    A5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Y     Y     N     N     Y    
2 Y     N     Y     Y     N    
3 N     Y     Y     Y     Y    
4 Y     Y     Y     N     N    
5 Y     Y     Y     N     N    
6 4     4     4     2     2
```

Comment: Thank you, two things, if we have many columns, the lookup table may not help. The other thing is that the sum for each column is missed. Can we do it better?

Comment: I don't understand "if we have many columns, the lookup table may not help." Don't you need to specify somehow what comparison value you want for each column? Is there some sort of other rule you want to use, e.g. "column number plus nine"?

Comment: I have updated my question, I want to count each column based on Ns. If you have 500 columns, you need to spend a lot of time for generating the lookup table.

Comment: In your question you define 5 values for n1 through n5. If you have 500 columns, don't you need to define 500 of them? If you don't, what is the logic you want to use? If you do, why is it easier to define 500 variables separately rather than put them in a table?